# Referencing an Excel Workbook/Worksheet that lives on Microsoft teams?

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-teams

I am working on a small VBA project in Excel and need to reference a main data sheet that is housed on my companies microsoft teams drive. The workbook I am referencing it from is also on the teams drive in the same folder. I currently am referencing it in a way that allows the code to work while both workbooks are open
`Set datawkb = Excel.Workbooks("PM Planner 2023.xlsx")`
but not when the referenced workbook is closed. Its been a while since ive played around with VBA and am wondering if anyone can help me out here?

Comment: You can use `Workbooks.Open(urlHere)` to open the workbook if it's not already open.

Comment: A "workbook in teams" is a "workbook in SharePoint" effectively, so you can use the URL of the workbook on the team site.